# JPQL query in Spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Lets say we have :

```
class Range {
  public long start;
  public long end;
}
```

This JPA entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entry")
public class Entry {
  @Id
  long id;

  @OneToMany
  Set<Individual> individuals;
}
```

another JPA entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="individual")
public class Individual {
  @Id
  long id;

  long code;

  @ManyToOne
  Entry entry;
}
```

and a controller:

```
public class IndexedEntryController {
  EntityManagerFactory emf;

  List<Entry> find(List<Range> lst) {
    String str = "";

    for(Range r:lst) {
      if(!str.isEmpty) {
        str += " or ";
      }
      str += "(i.code between " + r.start + " and " + r.end + ")";
    }

    String query = "Select i.entry from Individual i where " + str + " group by i.entry having count(i) > " + lst.size()-1;
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
  }
}
```

This query returns all entries that have `n-1` individuals with code between one of  specific ranges, where `n` is number of ranges.

I want to move to Spring `JpaRepository`. How can I implement this query with a `JpaRepository`?

Comment: Your code doesn't look right.  It will generate invalid SQL such as `or (i.code between 1 and 9)(i.code between 11 and 19)(i.code between 21 and 29)` if `lst` contains more than one `Range`.  See your code running [here](http://ideone.com/UIKvsA).  The overall query will also be invalid even with a single `Range` (`where or (...)`).  Besides that, you can convert this into a native SQL query and run that via any JPA repository as a native query.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when writing the post . It is if(!str.isEmpty())

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, create a regular `JpaRepository` for `Entry` with a method like `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "?1") List<Entry> findByQuery(String query);` and pass your pre-built query to this method.  Just keep in mind that what you are doing is prone to SQL Injection attacks as you are building the query by directly concatenating values.